# Segmentation Fault when trying to index an array of arrays of objects via a pointer

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, sfml

Can someone please tell me why I get a segmentation fault running this? I try and a pointer to an array of an array of objects, how I can fix this problem? The declaration of the sf::Vector2 class can be found here: http://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/1.6/classsf_1_1Vector2.php

Many thanks.

```
#include <SFML/System/Vector2.hpp>
#include <iostream>
class Tet
{
    public:
        Tet();
   private:
        static sf::Vector2 <int> I[4];
        static sf::Vector2 <int> J[4];
        static sf::Vector2 <int> *types[2];

};

sf::Vector2 <int> Tet::I[4] = {sf::Vector2 <int>(0,1),
                               sf::Vector2 <int>(1,1),
                               sf::Vector2 <int>(2,1),
                               sf::Vector2 <int>(3,1)};

sf::Vector2 <int> Tet::J[4] = {sf::Vector2 <int>(1,1),
                               sf::Vector2 <int>(2,1),
                               sf::Vector2 <int>(3,1),
                               sf::Vector2 <int>(3,2)};

sf::Vector2 <int>* Tet::types[2] = { I,J };                                   

Tet::Tet()
{
    //trying to print out x member of first vector of I 
    std::cout << (*(*(types))).x << std::endl; 
}

main()
{
    Tet t = Tet();
}
```

EDIT: g++ compiler

Comment: What is an sf::Vector2 and how is it implemented?  Just looking at the code one would assume it should work.  Can you reproduce this with types that are more widely available, because without access to sf::Vector2 no one is going to be able to take this could and try it out.

Comment: As expected, a simple example (replace sf::Vector2<int> with char) seems to work.

Comment: it is defined here http://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/1.6/Vector2_8hpp_source.php

Comment: Manually dragging in the `Vector2` implementation this works as expected under Visual Studio 2010.  What compiler are you using?

Answer (score 1):

You never allocate or instantiate the `types` array you are referencing. `types` is a pointer you can't assign concrete values to a `nullptr` which is how you left it at the moment.

Just declare it as an array instead of a pointer
`sf::Vector2<int> types[2][4];`

You may want to consider a simpler more effective design perhaps by having a `Vector2` object, a `Matrix` object, and then the `Tet` object which has a collection of matrices using STL containers and algorithms preferably.

Comment: Thanks. I wanted to be able to index the types array and return either I or J depending upon the index value (0 or 1) returned by a pseudo-random number generator

Comment: You'd probably be best with the array and leaving pointers out of this then so you don't need to worry about memory management.

Comment: I guess I could declare a 2D array of sf::Vector2 <int> then instead like sf::Vector2 <int>[2][4]

Comment: He has created an array of pointers, and assigned them values to valid data.  There is no need to allocate any additional memory.

Comment: @Chad:  the example code correctly creates an array of pointers, but incorrectly assigns an array of objects to it.  That mismatch is the problem.  I can't figure out why VS 2010 accepts the code, though.

Answer (score 1):

maybe allocate types first and initialize with { &I, &J }